# How to save results to csv using python scraper?

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I found this python code to scrape twitter by custom search queries:

https://github.com/tomkdickinson/Twitter-Search-API-Python/blob/master/TwitterScraper.py

I want to store the results from this code to a csv file.

I tried adding the csv writer at around line 245 within the for loop that prints out the tweets as per my search query but the csv file results as blank

```
def save_tweets(self, tweets):
    """
    Just prints out tweets
    :return: True always
    """
    for tweet in tweets:
        # Lets add a counter so we only collect a max number of tweets
        self.counter += 1
        if tweet['created_at'] is not None:
            t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((tweet['created_at']/1000))
            fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            myCsvRow = log.info("%i [%s] - %s" % (self.counter, t.strftime(fmt), tweet['text']))
            fd = open('document.csv','a')
            fd.write(myCsvRow)
            fd.close()

    return True
```

Also, There is a comment in the code at around line 170 that mentions:

```
@abstractmethod
def save_tweets(self, tweets):
    """
    An abstract method that's called with a list of tweets.
    When implementing this class, you can do whatever you want with these tweets.
    """
```

How can I use this class to save the tweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the line:

```
myCsvRow = log.info("%i [%s] - %s" % (self.counter, t.strftime(fmt), tweet['text']))
```

Looking at the code on the GitHub page you're using, I can see `log` is a python logger. [`log.info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.info)'s purpose is to write the string that it is given somewhere (ex: the console, a file, or any combination of these or other places). It does not return a value, thus `myCsvRow` will be empty.

What you want is more likely:

```
myCsvRow = "%i [%s] - %s" % (self.counter, t.strftime(fmt), tweet['text'])
```

Although, a couple notes on that:

(1) You are not putting commas between the entries, which is common for CSVs (CSV = Comma Separated Values), and

(2) It's actually kind of risky to try to write out a csv line when one of your fields is a text field that could potentially contain commas. If you naively just write out the text as-is, a comma in the tweet itself would cause whatever is interpreting the CSV to think that there are extra CSV fields in the row. Luckily python comes with a [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library that will help you avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip!